# How much bandwidth is used by security updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, bandwidth, patch

Does anyone have a ballpark figure on how much bandwidth is used on average each month by Windows 7 for security updates / patches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An average month would depend on how many updates (vulnerability) have been released in that month, My option would be around 50MB to 700MB a month.

One could look at the "**Size**" on the site of "**Windows Update**".

[image]

Or monitor their traffic to the domain

> *.microsoft.com

Or

> microsoft.com

Comment: I guess if I installed a fresh copy and then monitored the traffic as I download the updates that would give a good estimate. I was just hoping someone else would have done it first :)